# Notepad++ Remove all characters at beginning of line before alpha character

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, and have gotten close, but not quite there. What I'm trying to do is remove all characters in every line before the first alpha character.

Input:

```
1. Bunch of text
1.1 Some more text.
1.2 Even more text.
2. New text
2.1 New subtext
2.1.1 New sub-subtext
```

Expected output:

```
Bunch of text
Some more text.
Even more text.
New text
New subtext
New sub-subtext
```

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2rnd.png), which will remove everything except the spaces/tabs.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

Find string : `^[0-9. ]*(.*)`
Replace string : `\1`

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is there a way to have it look for tabs there as well? Usually, the sub-subtext lines have a tab instead of a space. If not, I can always just use \t to get rid of those in one extra step, but it would be awesome to have all be in the same expression.

Comment: The tab character is `\t`, so use the search string of : `^[0-9. \t]*(.*)`

Comment: You are my hero lol. I couldn't figure out where to put the stupid \t.

Comment: \s will also look for whitespace characters and will match both space and tab

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^a-z]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  [^a-z]+       # 1 or more any character that is not a letter
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Bunch of text
Some more text.
Even more text.
New text
New subtext
New sub-subtext
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]